# Typescript: define type of an object

Tags: object, types, typescript

I want to define the type of an Object literal, with key valye pairs, like below. In any way can't manage this. Please help.

```
export const endPoints: {name: string: {method: string; url: string;}} = {
  allFeed: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json'
  },
  topFeed: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/algo.json'
  },
  followingFeed: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/following.json'
  },
  defaultFeed: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json/my_feed.json'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, should be:

```
const endPoints: { [name: string]: { method: string; url: string; } } = {
    allFeed: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json'
    },
    ...
};
```

You can also use interfaces:

```
interface EndPoint {
    method: string;
    url: string;
}

interface EndPointMap {
    [name: string]: EndPoint;
}

const endPoints: EndPointMap = {
    ...
}
```

Or types:

```
type EndPoint = {
    method: string;
    url: string;
}

type EndPointMap = {
    [name: string]: EndPoint;
}

const endPoints: EndPointMap = {
    ...
}
```

Which makes the code more readable in my opinion (when compared to the inline way of declaring the type)

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)